# Audit give-away on deleted posts with comments

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-answers, review-audits

I was doing a review, and came across a Very Low Quality answer that I was going to recommend for deletion, but only after leaving a detailed comment to help the poster learn for the future. I typed up the comment, then was greeted with the infamous `You cannot comment on deleted/locked posts` message. Since this was in the Review Queue, obviously it was an audit to make sure I wasn't robo-reviewing, and I clicked on the Delete (no comment) button.

Of course, I passed. I feel this is a bug since anyone could just copy and paste a 15-character message into the Comment field, and determine if the post was deleted. I'd suggest making it "look" like the comment was added, to help make audits a little more challenging.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: If anything, the bug is that pressing the Add Comment button doesn't just complete review and pass the audit. Plenty of people have gone to MSO and complained that they thought it meant the post had already been handled, so they click the No Action Needed or Looks OK button thinking there's nothing left for them to do.

Comment: @animuson Then that would be a usability problem, wouldn't it?

Comment: You're complaining about the red error message giving away the audit, but if the Add Comment button *doesn't* pass the audit, then what exactly would you expect to happen? Clicking the button just does... nothing? Fake comments seem like a waste of code to me. Making that button instantly pass the audit is the only logical solution in my opinion.

Comment: If you are taking the trouble to post a comment, you are not a robo-reviewer, so there is no problem in giving away that it is a test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary purpose of the audit is to catch roboreviewers.  Those people who just click 'looks good' on everything and do the reviews within seconds of each other.

It can be argued if a secondary purpose is that of guiding people to understand the community viewpoint.  This is arguable and isn't the point of the audit.

By typing in sufficient text into the comment area you have identified yourself as not a roboreviewer.  That part of the audit is complete once you realize "this is and audit" because you've taken the time to *not* robo review.

> [image]

That's what a robo-reviewer looks like in the first post queue.  The time between those reviews is a matter of seconds - about the time it takes to load the page.

There may be a usability glitch in this.  However, the point of the audit has been served and you are not a roboreviewer.

**Giving away an audit to someone who spends time on the review is not a problem.**

Answer (score 2):

The post may have been deleted while you were reviewing it. That has happened to me, and usually if you leave the review and go look at the post, you'll see that it has already been deleted.